# False java.net.BindException: Address already in use on Jetty

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, jetty, rhel

On my CI server I have a test that needs to start Jetty server.
The test goes like this:

1. Generate random port (using java rand in legit TCP port range).
2. Validate using Linux's `fuser` to check that port in not in use
3. Run the tests

Occasionally, even after validating the port is free, I get the exception:

---

```
WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:49277 FAILED: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:272)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:364)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunWarMojo.execute(JettyRunWarMojo.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

---

The test that runs on:

- RHEL 6.3 host
- Maven 3.0.4
- jetty-maven-plugin:7.5.4
- Java 1.7.51

What can possibly be the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like there is a process runnning on port `49277`

Comment: But I verified no process is running just before... by running 'fuser'

Answer (score 4):

There is a process on port `49277` already when Jetty attempts to startup.

No way around that.

You can ask Linux what's listening, and see what process is using that port.

```
$ netstat -tlnp
```

However, if all you want is a random port that Jetty can startup and listen on, just set the port that Jetty should use to `0`, and that will tell [TCP to randomly assign an available port when binding for listening](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int)).

Your task then, is to figure out what port Jetty is listening on after startup.

Comment: Thanks! That's really weird 49277 is generated random port. Moreover, as written, I verify that this port is free by running "fuser" just before jetty execution. Is there any chance the port validation is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using tomcat on 8080 port please stop the tomcat server and run jetty from maven again.